# How does Windows actually detect LAN (proxy) settings when using Automatic Configuration

Tags: windows, proxy, lan

When *Windows Internet Properties -> Connections -> LAN Settings -> Automatic Configuration* is set to *"Automatically detect settings"* how does Windows actually determine/discover what the settings are? Is it a network broadcast or some kind of targeted query to a server configured somewhere in the registry, or something else?

Comment: This is because in your organization proxy settings are probably distributed through DHCP (or maybe group policy), whereas Chrome only supports the discovery through DNS described in my answer.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Its simple: Browsers (Firefox works the same) query `GET http://wpad/wpad.dat`.

If a web server named wpad is resolveable, it should serve wpad.dat, a script file analog to netscape PAC files. MIME type must also be "application/x-ns-proxy-autoconfig".

Answer (score 9):

This [info](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Proxy_Autodiscovery_Protocol) about WPAD (Web Proxy Auto Discovery) seems to describe the process in detail, though I have confirmed that what Tomalak says is also actually occurring.

Answer (score 8):

It's a network broadcast, usually using [DHCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dhcp).

That there wikipedia page should tell you all you need to know.

Comment: I suppose the people who modded this down didn't know that this broken auto-configuration protocol first queries the DHCP server, and only then goes on to try the usual list of default wpad-like URLs.

Comment: I believe in MS DHCP config you can specify the proxy server.

Comment: Yes, DHCP is/was used by Microsoft. Other implementations vary.

Comment: Help! How can I see what the DHCP is broadcasting about proxies?

Answer (score 8):

The IE configuration described enables a WPAD implementation. Here's the [Microsoft explanation of the entire mechanism](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc713344.aspx) (probably too much detail for a single post).

Answer (score -5):

•Go to Tools > Options > General > Connection Settings >
•Set to “Manual Proxy Configuration”