# How to get dynamic proxy settings from IE?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, internet-explorer, proxy

I have .Net 3.5 WinForms application that require access to the Internet. But my company network uses dynamic proxy settings shown below. All my attempts to retrieve and use this setting got fail.
How to use this proxy in .net application?
[image: Proxy Settings]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please go through the following link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300743.aspx

Answer (score 0):

By default the .NET framework will use whatever proxy settings setup on the local machine. So what you asked should be done automatically.
Check DefaultProxy setting in your config file .

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kd3cf2ex%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

But default every HttpWebRequest should automatically be filled out with this information.
See [C# Getting proxy settings from Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8808052/c-sharp-getting-proxy-settings-from-internet-explorer)