# "remote name could not be resolved" exception when trying to download response using .NET WebClient

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webrequest

I am trying to download a response from a certain website in order to confirm the site is up and to measure the response time (which is provided in the site content)

The page has url like `https://www.blabla.com.au/ServiceAvailability`

I can put in the page url in my browser and I can see the page is up and response time provided. I can also click the link and the page will load in the visual studio browser as well.

But when I try to call the same url from my application I get the following `System.Net.WebException`:

> {"The remote name could not be resolved: "www.blabla.com.au"}

The code is running on my local PC, I am also accessing the website from my local PC and can bring up the page from the browser and in VS

My code looks like this:

```
string myUrl ="https://www.blabla.com.au/ServiceAvailability";

using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
{ 
    result = webClient.DownloadString(myUrl);
}
```

where `result` is a `string`

I have tried the following to get around the problem:

1. Run visual studio as an administrator
2. Use my user name/ password as credentials instead of the default
3. Put an @ infront of the url
4. Tried using WebRequest and HttpWebRequest as per code blocks below:

   ```
   WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(myUrl);
   res = req.GetResponse();

   HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(myUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
   HttpWebResponse res = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
   ```

Comment: may be ssl could be an issue. do you need add a ssl certificate with the request?

Comment: Hi Aleksey, I don't think so because I have also tried using http://www.google.com.au as my url address

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possibility is your browser uses some proxy where your code does not (or use different one).

If it is the case make sure to set [WebClient.Proxy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.proxy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to match one in the browser.

If it is not proxy issue - check if DNS resolves correctly via external tools (like http://mxtoolbox.com/DNSLookup.aspx) - it is unlikely, but possible if browser uses different DNS than your code.

Comment: I think your answer is on the right track, I will try it out and vote your answer up if it turns out to be the issue

Comment: I was able to resolve my issue by making use of the WebProxy class  `using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient()) { webClient.Proxy = new WebProxy("myproxy.com"); result= webClient.DownloadString(someURL);}`

Comment: I got the same exception when trying to load [wikipedia] (http://www.en.wikipedia.org/). When debugging i found that the link was changed to "www.en.wikipedia.org" somehow. Tested the link(https://www.en.wikipedia.org/) in http://mxtoolbox.com/DNSLookup.aspx and that confirms that is down. Any reason why?

Comment: @LucasPalmaStabile feel free to ask new question instead of comment.

Comment: How can you find what the browser is using to plug into this? Thanks.

Comment: @AdamGarner https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8808052/c-sharp-getting-proxy-settings-from-internet-explorer and similar question should answer that. Otherwise please ask separate question.