# How do I make my program actually use a proxy I create?

Tags: c#, proxy, network-programming

There seem to be so many ways to create a `WebProxy`/`IWebProxy` and properties related to setting them. My question is: When I create a proxy, how do I actually use that proxy setting?

I can find options in `WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy`, `WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy()`, `WebRequest.Proxy`, etc. to create and assign new `WebProxy` instances but this confuses me... Where would a program typically "grab" the specified proxy settings from?

Quick edit: I did  notice that the `HttpWebClientProtocol` class seemed promising, but again, I'm not 100% sure as my proxy knowledge (and networking in general) is extremely limited...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have created a HttpWebRequest object, you can asign it a proxy.

```
HttpWebRequest myWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(myUrl);
string MyProxyHostString = "192.168.1.1";
int MyProxyPort = 3212;

//Here you asign the proxy to the HttpWebRequest 
myWebRequest.Proxy = new WebProxy(MyProxyHostString, MyProxyPort);
```

Comment: So if I set a (I'm assuming there are more types?) request, the application will go off of this specifically? If I were to do something like changing your line to something like `myWebRequest.Proxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy`, it would use system defaults?

Comment: I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8808052/c-sharp-getting-proxy-settings-from-internet-explorer
You're using the `WebRequest()`, so you can use this option
    `WebRequest.DefaultProxy = WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy();`