# Can eclipse auto-detect proxy settings?Or can at least create my own local plugin from the update site?

Tags: java, eclipse, networking, eclipse-plugin, epic

I have a linux machine inside a "closed" network. I.e. no access to the internet.
I have a mac machine that can access the internet.
I installed eclipse in both.
I need to install a plugin in eclipse specifically `EPIC` for `Perl` development.
The site offers a link to source forge for offline installation so I downloaded it and tried to install it in my linux machine.
**Problem here:** The offline version in source forge is old and does not work due to a dependency issue in another plugin of eclipse and this dependency is solved in newest versions of the plugin.
So at this point since the offline version can not work and I don't have access to the internet for the update site to get the latest version I am stuck.

Moving on to `Mac`:
I have access to the internet but when I add the update site to install the plugin it fails to connect.
But the url is accessible by the browser so I believe that it is due to proxy settings.
When I look at the browser's settings I see that it is set to `Auto detect proxy`. So I can not copy the proxy ip/port from browser. Also I don't understand how/where the browser finds the proxy to connect to.
Is there a way to make eclipse to auto-detect proxy settings as well? I don't see such an option in `Preferences->General->Network Connections`.

So what can I do as I am stuck in both cases!
On the top of my head if there was a way to somehow download the files from the update site and create a local installation it would solve my problem in both machines.
But is this possible? How?
What can I do to solve my problems?

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371176/downloading-eclipse-plug-in-update-sites-for-offline-installation

Comment: @LeeMeador:I have seen this answer.The link specifies that the command is deprecated and in the new version I am not sure how it would still solve my problems with proxy.I mean will it auto-detect my settings?

Comment: Eclipse has preferences -> general -> network connections to configure your proxy. Choose the type in the dropdown at the top. Select a type (like HTTP) and click 'edit'

Comment: @LeeMeador:I know how to configure a proxy in eclipse.This is not what I am asking.I am asking how to make eclipse auto-detect the proxy same as firefox does in my system. Otherwise where can I find the proxy to set it?

Comment: If you turn off the proxy completely in FireFox, does it fail to see the update site?

Comment: @LeeMeador:Yes it does.The configuration is:`Auto detect proxy settings`. I have no idea where it founds the proxy.

Comment: I apologize if it seems I am insulting your intelligence. That is not my intention. Perhaps it would be easiest if you took a thumb drive to a friend's computer on another network or at a coffee shop and use that. Or maybe someone else knows about how the Mac version of Firefox finds the proxy.

Comment: You also might find something about your network proxy from the system admins or help desk or whatever you have that controls the network.

Comment: @LeeMeador:Well taking the computer to another network is not an option.I am thinking about asking sysadmins but I was trying to research myself because I am afraid they will think my question would show high ignorance

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191023/how-does-windows-actually-detect-lan-proxy-settings-when-using-automatic-confi

Comment: @LeeMeador:The title says `Windows`.I am in Mac

Comment: Ok. Don't read it if you don't want to. I think it might help you. I could be wrong.

Comment: @LeeMeador:I will read it.

Comment: @LeeMeador:But it will solve only my problem in `Mac`.I still will not be able to work in the linux machine. No internet access there.Not possible to get access there due to security restrictions

Comment: Which version of EPIC do you want?

Comment: @LeeMeador:The offline (source-forge) is `EPIC 0.6.35` which does not work (known issue http://sourceforge.net/p/e-p-i-c/discussion/258688/thread/69402988) So I would like the newest possible

Comment: Try this: Go to the SF site (http://sourceforge.net/projects/e-p-i-c/files/) and download the version you want as source. Unzip it to a folder and see if you can install from the folder with site.xml in it.

Comment: @LeeMeador:I already downloaded the latest version in SF site and this is already deprecated (6.0.35) and does not work.Why this people in eclipse make it so complicated some times? The offline version is deprecated (i.e. useless since it does not work) and I can not use the online version.There must be a way to create an offline version from the online site.I hope there is one.

Comment: You can get source for latest version from https://github.com/jploski/epic-ide but I don't know about the update site.

Comment: @LeeMeador:This is indeed latest!But how can I create the local installation folder for installation in my eclipse from the source code in github?