# Persist automatic configuration for proxy on windows

Tags: windows, proxy, pac

I use a proxy automatic configuration for LAN settings, this is automatic and scripted in a pac file, same as stated in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/191023/1257607), the thing is that everytime I restart the computer, this configuration is lost. Is there a way to persist this configuration on *Internet Properties -> Connections -> LAN Settings -> Automatic Configuration*

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I use this tool with Chrome, maybe it can help

[Proxy -switchysharp](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/proxy-switchysharp/dpplabbmogkhghncfbfdeeokoefdjegm?hl=en)

Comment: I have tested it and works perfectly, I was thinking in writing a shell script of something, this is not automatic, but just a click away and works fine for me, thanks