# Git repository cloning timed-out error 443

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

I have downloaded the git and set name and email variables. When trying to clone the repository, facing 443 timeout issue. I am using a corporate machine, can this be the issue. Also, the http.proxy in git-config is null, is it required to set it to system IP?

Below error is faced:

> fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/XXXXXXXX/XXXXX.git/': Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Timed out

I found a post asking to use :

```
git config --global http.proxy 
http://proxyUsername:proxyPassword@proxy.server.com:port
```

What is proxyUsername, proxyPassword,proxy.server.com, port here? Where can I check these in my machine? (Windows 7)

Answer (score 0):

http://babel.jorgebg.com/configure-proxy-windows-7

The above link has instructions on how to setup proxy on Windows 7. If you follow the sequence, and your system has a preconfigured proxy server, you can find the values you're looking for in the final window.

Use them in your configuration and you're good to go, hopefully.

Comment: In LAN settings, Use proxy server is unchecked. Infact only Automatically detect setting is checked. So, I --unset the http.proxy globally but still the below error is coming.

fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/UserName/Repository_Name.git/': Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Timed out

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191023/how-does-windows-actually-detect-lan-proxy-settings-when-using-automatic-confi

Try this, then. The above answer was under the assumption you may be able to find something there.